How to add imageUploader Ui component on checkout form in Magento 2.4
i want to know how we can use imageUploader UI Component on checkout form. For some strange reason I don't want to create uiComponenet file. I want to directly use imageUploader ui component in checkout_index_index.xml file. How can I do it? Thankyou in advance
